# Laravel 4 generate:migration Error

Tags: php, terminal, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I'm not too sure why this is happening. I am able to generate:seed with no issues,but when I do anything with migration I keep getting the same error as you see below.

```
php artisan generate:migration create_Post_table --fields="title:varchar, body:text"

Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"fopen(\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/DRCSports\/bootstrap\/compiled.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/DRCSports\/vendor\/classpreloader\/classpreloader\/src\/ClassPreloader\/Command\/PreComp
```

Comment: Have you got writeable permissions to the `bootstrap` directory?

Comment: drwxrwxr-x@  6 rachaelhill  admin     204 Jun  3 14:05 bootstrap

Comment: I got it working! Thank you, it wasn't so much my permissions on bootstrap, but my complied.php in my bootstrap folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have writeable permissions to both the `bootstrap` directory and the `compiled.php` file.